# Illegal character in opaque part at index 2 flutter

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

I make a flutter project on windows using android studio, it work properly but now i used MAC OS and when i coppied my code on MAC  it run on simulator perfectly but it gives error when i run it on android emulator. I am new for MAC OS and no idea about this error. I user android studio for coding.

```
Error log

Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:flutterBuildDebug'.
> java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in opaque part at index 2: 
C:\\Users\\Boffin\

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: @GursewakSingh please follow https://flutter.io/setup-macos/ to get started on macOS.

Comment: @Sebastian Roth i face this issue only with windows coppied project all other projects created on MAC OS work properly

Comment: @GursewakSingh In that case please try running `flutter create` in the same folder as your project in order to re-create all the IDE files & path configurations to the SDK.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please try running `flutter create` in the same folder as your project in order to re-create all the IDE files & path configurations to the SDK.

This is sometimes necessary after platform upgrades or when moving code from one developer PC to the other.

Comment: I tried that, still not working after command was successful.

Comment: @BarbaricGamester open a new question and post the output of flutter doctor etc. Also please make sure you’re using the latest version.

Comment: please more description with what do i need to replace for example windows to mac or reverse.

Answer (score 58):

I met the same issue, `flutter clean` saved me.

Answer (score 9):

For me, I have deleted `build` folder inside `android/app` and now my issue has been solved

Comment: After deleting the `build` remember to `flutter clean` and then `flutter run`

Answer (score 5):

Delete file `flutter_build.d` in `/android/app/build/intermediates/flutter/debug/`
and rebuild

Answer (score 2):

`Flutter clean` is a good idea, but please ensure you're also deploying to an iOS device and have not accidentedly connected and android device.

Answer (score 2):

## Build cleanup

This error happened to me after copying the entire project that was on the windows operating system and pasted on a MAC OS operating system.

I solved the problem by typing the command in the terminal directly in Android Studio

```
flutter clean
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what your issue is you can try the following, Generally:

1. Flutter clean

However, if you just moved an android folder which has a key, you'll have to:

2. Update the **storeFile** path in the **key.properties** file in Android to be the location of your new folders key.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your error came while you build app for `android`. Usually, this happens when there is a folder created inside the `android/app` directory called `build`. You can delete the entire `build` directory. Else you can also delete the whole `android` directory and create again with
`flutter create .` command.

Answer (score 0):

yeah, flutter clean, flutter pub get work for me, but I think upload project to github is best option rather then shifting project from one laptop to other.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the existing build folder and try running the build command again. Worked in my case.
I was building the APK using `--split-per-abi` in my GitHub repo CI/CD but every time it was throwing the same error until I realized I pushed the code without the .gitignore file and the build folder was present in my repo.